# Django: Trying to organize django fixtures

Tags: django, django-admin, fixtures

I've some models created wich i'd like to provide initial data for. The problem is that there are several models, and i'd like to organize the data.

Currently, i've a big JSON file: `initial_data.json` with the data. I was thinking i could use some comments, but JSON has no comments! I really want to use json.

So, the file is like:

```
[
  {
    "model": "app1.Model1",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "nombre": "A convenir con el vendedor"
    }
  },
//many more
  {
    "model": "app2.Model1",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "nombre": "A convenir con el vendedor"
    }
  },
//many more
  {
    "model": "app2.Model1",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "nombre": "A convenir con el vendedor"
    }
  },
]
```

So, i thought i could organize them in different files, and with some initial script load them. The idea is not issue several `python manage.py loaddata thisApp.Model` But, then it would be difficult to separate the files that are not ment to be loaded at initial time.

Here are the files as example:

```
+app1
   +fixtures
      model1.json
      model2.json
+app2
   +fixtures
      model1.json
      model2.json
+app3
   +fixtures
      model1.json
      model2.json
```

Do you have any idea how to keep simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like you said, create several files, and write a script that combines them into `initial_data.json` and invokes the needed `django.core.management` command. this is what I do.

Comment: I think i didn't write it good. My english is not very good. The problem is: in every fixtures folder will be initial data, and other data. How could you tell them apart?

Comment: if you use some sort of a naming convention for your files your script can tell them apart using their names. for example, use the prefix initial_data for the files that you want to combine to initial_data.json. for example, initial_data_1.json, etc. do I understand the problem correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Call the files that contain initial data "initial_data.json" - syncdb will only load those. You can load the others manually with manage.py loaddata.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures